# How to remove extra line that appears in between logo and content

Tags: html, css

I want the white content to be directly against the logo but a blank line is appearing between them although I set margin-top to 0.

```
<body background="$request.getContextPath()/images/background.gif">

<img src="$request.getContextPath()/images/logo.gif" />

     <div class="content">
```

This is the css

```
img {
margin-top:0;
```

}

```
.content {
background: white;
margin-left:5%;

width: 779px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 273px;
border:0;
margin-top:0;
```

}

```
body {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.5;
border:0;
margin-top:0;
```

}

Comment: Can you create a codepen and give a link the codepen so that we can see what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try a negative margin like so

```
.content {
margin-top: -10px;
}
```